# Intrinsic matrix after image rectification using cv2.StereoRectify

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I want to do image rectification and undistortion for a pair of images. I already have the intrinsic matrix(`k_left`), projection matrix(`p_left` which I didn't use), distortion coef(`d_left`) and transformation of two camera coordinates (`R,T`). So my code is:

```
r1, r2, p1, p2, q, roi1, roi2 = cv2.stereoRectify(k_left, d_left, k_right, d_right,
                                                  (img_height, img_width),
                                                  R,T,flags=cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY)

map1x, map1y = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(
    cameraMatrix=k_left,
    distCoeffs=d_left,
    R=r1,
    newCameraMatrix=p1,
    size=(img_width, img_height),
    m1type=cv2.CV_32FC1)

map2x, map2y = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(
    cameraMatrix=k_right,
    distCoeffs=d_right,
    R=r2,
    newCameraMatrix=p2,
    size=(img_width, img_height),
    m1type=cv2.CV_32FC1)
img1_rect = cv2.remap(img1, map1x, map1y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
img2_rect = cv2.remap(img2, map2x, map2y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

My question is:

1. After this rectification and undistortion, can I still use the old
   intrinsic matrix for my further processing? If not, how can I obtain
   the new intrinsic matrix?
2. My understanding is: since I already have
   `k_left` and `p_left`, I can compute the original extrinsic matrix
   as `ex_left = np.linalg.inv(k_left) @ p_left`, then the extrinsic matrix after rectification/undistortion is simply `ex_left_rect = r1 @ ex_left`, and I can compute the new intrinsic matrix as: `k_left_rect = p1 @ np.linalg.pinv(ex_left_rect)`. Is this a correct method or do I miss something?
3. I check the doc of cv2.StereoRectify and the output projection
   matrix I obtained: `P1 = [f 0 cx1 0; 0 f cy 0; 0 0 1 0], P2 =[f 0 cx2 Tx*f; 0 f cy 0; 0 0 1 0]` I think these two projections means that the extrinsic matrix of first camera is just "no transformation" and the extrinsic matrix of second camera is just "a translation". But I think this is not the real case. How do I understand these two projection matrices from the output of cv2.stereorectify?

Thanks in advance!